# MySQL Create Index "Server is unreachable"

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I've a very large table in a mysql database with innodb engine.

Now i want to introduce a new index with the following script:

After some minutes it tells me:

> ERROR: Error when running failback script. Details follow. ERROR 2006:
>   MySQL server has gone away"

Does this i mean i only have an timeout?

Comment: That's a bit sparse information. Give us one more hint...

Comment: Unfortunately i don't have any. I use the workbend choose alter table , add an index and when the script is executing it takes some minutes and trhen i got this exception message.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the MySQL server's wait_timeout.

First of all check the current one by running:

`SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'wait_timeout';`

The default is 28800 which is too much to have any problems.

The second one is the innodb_lock_wait_timeout.

`SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb_lock_wait_timeout';` which the default is 50.

More info about these system variables:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_lock_wait_timeout

If the table is too large or you can't change the system vars, try table partitioning.